# Android SDK wont open

Tags: android, sdk

I have tried a lot of the solutions to this problem I have seen here but none seem to work for me.
Basically when I run the Android batch file a CMD box pops up for a millisecond and closes again.
I can see that it says: "find_java.exe was unexpected at this time".

I have no idea why this is happening. I think it might be because I am not installing it onto the main hard drive that my OS is on, which is an SSD, but instead installing it onto a second drive.

So the file path to the JDK is:
F:\Program Files (x64)\Java\jdk1.7.0_11

Anybody know how I could fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I found a way to fix it. Go to the System32 folder and change java to java.exe, hopefully this will work. Also make sure you have jdk and jre installed. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running windows make sure that you have a system variable named JAVA_HOME set to point to your Java home directory

JAVA_HOME  =  F:\Program Files (x64)\Java\jre6  (or whatever version your JRE is)

and add

F:\Program Files (x64)\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin  to the PATH system variable

Notice the \bin added to the end there

Comment: Yeah that's how I have it set up and it still doesn't work. I'm running Windows 8 if that makes a difference at all?

Comment: @AndyOHart - it shouldn't matter. I have multiple Windows 8 systems running the SDK. Change your JAVA_HOME to the JRE path. I think I mistakenly assumed that the JDK path was ok there.